# Get object by its `id` in an AIR windowedApplication

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, air

There may be a better way of doing this...so please suggest if there is.

I've got some javascript that calls an AIR function. This AIR functions creates a new HTML element and adds it to the "Stage" like so:

```
// guid is the ID given to the new window (HTML element) by javascript
private function createNewWindow(guid:String):void {
    var frame:HTML = new HTML();
    frame.id = guid;

    addElement(frame);
}
```

Now I've also got a function that sets the `location` of the frame based on its id...this is where I'm struggling.

```
// set the location of the window referenced by it's id (guid)
private function setLocation(guid:String, location:String):void {
    // psuedocode. Obviously it won't work.
    stage.getById(guid).location = location;
}
```

**So, how do I "get" my HTML element based on its ID?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you don't.  This isn't javascript, this is a OO language and as such, you need to change your thought process.  What are you trying to do? Create several html windows within an air application?  If you want to have an id based approach, you're going to need to store the id and the pointer to the component in an data structure (like a dictionary).

```
private var _components:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
this._components['someId'] = someComponent;
```

And from there you can add a function that just saves/returns the components.  I'm not entirely sure what's your approach and what you're trying to accomplish, but my gut tells me you're not doing something right.

Comment: "but my gut tells me you're not doing something right." haha. very true! You are correct in your assumption. I'll be creating several HTML windows and will be interactive with them VIA javascript. I just finished writing a `getFrameById` method that looped through an array of all the frames that have been added, checking their ids along the way. `Dictionary` is perfect.

Comment: And a side note: Javascript often mascarades as an OO language to some degree. Now that I know that there isn't a [reliable] built-in `getById` I should be able to do a near-direct port of my javascript application to Actionscript. The fact that their is a `this.getChildByName("myid")` function available is what lead me down the wrong path. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can I ask exactly 'why' you're doing this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Basically I'm just creating a tabbed browser in AIR

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, but why do you need them to talk to each other?  I think there are better ways of doing what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: They won't be talking to each other. There is one main HTML "element" that will control the tabs.

Comment: Oh, so you're creating a web browser in html within a web browser? Why not use air to do that?

Comment: eh, I <3 javascript and loathe Actionscript. haha. Ok, I don't LOATHE it. The "browser" also needs to be mostly "demoable" in the regular browser (well, webkit and gecko engines). So, instead of maintaining separate branches for browser and AIR I developed browser-side first and am trying to keep most of the functionality browser-based. Ideally, I'd like to port it to [Chromeless](http://mozillalabs.com/chromeless/) whenever Mozilla gets something stable/secure together.